# Stop ng-repeat and then resume it

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I'm using AngularJs and I have to display several arrays contained within an object structure like the following one:

```
$scope.familiesReport = {
    fathersAndChildren : [
        {
            name: "John",
            surname: "Doe",
            address: "Fake Street 123",
            hobbies: [
                {
                    activity: "fishing",
                    preferredOn: "Sunday" 
                },
                {
                    activity: "grappling",
                    preferredOn: "Thursday"
                },
                {
                    activity: "meditating",
                    preferredOn: "Monday"
                }
            ],
            familySize: 2,
            familyMembers: [
                {
                    name: "John"
                },
                {
                    name: "Carl"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Carl",
            surname: "Doe",
            address: "Fake Street 123",
            hobbies: [
                {
                    activity: "reading",
                    preferredOn: "Tuesday" 
                },
                {
                    activity: "swimming",
                    preferredOn: "Friday"
                }
            ],
            familySize: 0,
            familyMembers: 0
        },
        {
            name: "James",
            surname: "Dwight",
            address: "False Street 234",
            hobbies: [
                {
                    activity: "footing",
                    preferredOn: "Sunday" 
                },
                {
                    activity: "driving",
                    preferredOn: "Tuesday"
                },
                {
                    activity: "eating",
                    preferredOn: "Monday"
                }
            ],
            familySize: 0,
            familyMembers: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Juan",
            surname: "Derrick",
            address: "Faint Street 345",
            hobbies: [
                {
                    activity: "walking",
                    preferredOn: "Sunday" 
                },
                {
                    activity: "praying",
                    preferredOn: "Monday"
                }
            ],
            familySize: 0,
            familyMembers: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Jim",
            surname: "Delano",
            address: "Phony Street 456",
            hobbies: [
                {
                    activity: "cooking",
                    preferredOn: "Monday" 
                },
                {
                    activity: "repairing",
                    preferredOn: "Thursday"
                }
            ],
            familySize: 0,
            familyMembers: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Jacob",
            surname: "Dolan",
            address: "Foo Street 567",
            hobbies: [
                {
                    activity: "snorkling",
                    preferredOn: "Friday" 
                },
                {
                    activity: "playing",
                    preferredOn: "Monday"
                },
                {
                    activity: "chatting",
                    preferredOn: "Wednsday"
                }
            ],
            familySize: 0,
            familyMembers: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Jamal",
            surname: "Downey",
            address: "Fuu Street 123",
            hobbies: [
                {
                    activity: "diving",
                    preferredOn: "Tuesday" 
                },
                {
                    activity: "smoking",
                    preferredOn: "Sunday"
                }
            ],
            familySize: 0,
            familyMembers: 0
        },
    ];
}
```

Both father and child are the same type of object, **and neither this fact neither the whole structure of the array can be changed**, for now.

This array is created to respect one rule: if a father has some children, they are placed just after him in the array, furthermore if he has `familySize: 2`, it means that he has only 1 child; eventually, all the children must have `familySize: 0` and `familyMembers: 0`.

To sum it all up, in this example only John has just 1 child, Carl, while the other fathers have no children.

**My goal**

I need an `ng-repeat` to display the family units, so when a father has a child both must be shown in the same family unit just like this:

```
FAMILY: Doe         ADDRESS: Fake Street 123
________________________________________
|   John prefers fishing on Sunday      |
|           and grappling on Thursday   |
|           and meditating on Monday    |
|                                       |
|   CHILDREN                            |
|   Carl prefers reading on Tuesday     |
|           and swimming on Friday      |
|_______________________________________|

FAMILY: Dwight      ADDRESS: False Street 234
________________________________________
|   James prefers footing on Sunday     |
|           and driving on Tuesday      |
|           and eating on Monday        |
|_______________________________________|

FAMILY: Derrick     ADDRESS: Faint Street 345
________________________________________
|   Juan prefers walking on Sunday      |
|           and praying on Tuesday      |
|_______________________________________|

FAMILY: Delano      ADDRESS: Phony Street 456
________________________________________
|   Jim prefers cooking on Monday       |
|           and repairing on Thursday   |
|_______________________________________|

FAMILY: Dolan       ADDRESS: Foo Street 567
________________________________________
|   Jacob prefers snorkling on Friday   |
|           and playing on Monday       |
|           and chatting on Wednsday    |
|_______________________________________|

FAMILY: Downey      ADDRESS: Fuu Street 123
________________________________________
|   Jamal prefers diving on Tuesday     |
|           and smoking on Sunday       |
|_______________________________________|
```

**The problem**

In the `ng-repeat` when I find a father with a child, like John, I can't figure out how to show him with his children in the same family unit and then resume the loop from the first item after all the members of his family.

> Keep in mind that I can't loop through the `familyMembers` property,
>   since I'll lose the `hobby` property information, which has to be
>   displayed too.

**The struggle**

Is real.

Do you have any suggestion on how to reach my goal?

> **MAJOR EDIT:**
>
> Since I have been asked to provide some HTML (*which I probably won't be able to write since the renewed complexity of my problem, but I'm struggling to make it*) I gave a second look to the code I'm trying to "mime" here, and unfortunately I had to make some major edit in my question.
>
> Sorry.

Comment: Can you post the html you have now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here how you can do it; basically you need to group your records by family. I used [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#)'s groupBy function. Then I used `key,value` structure of `ng-repeat` to iterate through object created by [groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) function of underscore.

```
$scope.families = _.groupBy($scope.fathersAndChildren, function(fatherAndChildren) {
    return fatherAndChildren.surname;
  });
```

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.familiesReport = {
    fathersAndChildren: [{
      name: "John",
      surname: "Doe",
      address: "Fake Street 123",
      hobbies: [{
        activity: "fishing",
        preferredOn: "Sunday"
      }, {
        activity: "grappling",
        preferredOn: "Thursday"
      }, {
        activity: "meditating",
        preferredOn: "Monday"
      }],
      familySize: 2,
      familyMembers: [{
        name: "John"
      }, {
        name: "Carl"
      }]
    }, {
      name: "Carl",
      surname: "Doe",
      address: "Fake Street 123",
      hobbies: [{
        activity: "reading",
        preferredOn: "Tuesday"
      }, {
        activity: "swimming",
        preferredOn: "Friday"
      }],
      familySize: 0,
      familyMembers: 0
    }, {
      name: "James",
      surname: "Dwight",
      address: "False Street 234",
      hobbies: [{
        activity: "footing",
        preferredOn: "Sunday"
      }, {
        activity: "driving",
        preferredOn: "Tuesday"
      }, {
        activity: "eating",
        preferredOn: "Monday"
      }],
      familySize: 0,
      familyMembers: 0
    }, {
      name: "Juan",
      surname: "Derrick",
      address: "Faint Street 345",
      hobbies: [{
        activity: "walking",
        preferredOn: "Sunday"
      }, {
        activity: "praying",
        preferredOn: "Monday"
      }],
      familySize: 0,
      familyMembers: 0
    }, {
      name: "Jim",
      surname: "Delano",
      address: "Phony Street 456",
      hobbies: [{
        activity: "cooking",
        preferredOn: "Monday"
      }, {
        activity: "repairing",
        preferredOn: "Thursday"
      }],
      familySize: 0,
      familyMembers: 0
    }, {
      name: "Jacob",
      surname: "Dolan",
      address: "Foo Street 567",
      hobbies: [{
        activity: "snorkling",
        preferredOn: "Friday"
      }, {
        activity: "playing",
        preferredOn: "Monday"
      }, {
        activity: "chatting",
        preferredOn: "Wednsday"
      }],
      familySize: 0,
      familyMembers: 0
    }, {
      name: "Jamal",
      surname: "Downey",
      address: "Fuu Street 123",
      hobbies: [{
        activity: "diving",
        preferredOn: "Tuesday"
      }, {
        activity: "smoking",
        preferredOn: "Sunday"
      }],
      familySize: 0,
      familyMembers: 0
    }, ]
  }

  $scope.families = _.groupBy($scope.familiesReport.fathersAndChildren, function(fatherAndChildren) {
    return fatherAndChildren.surname;
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in families">
    <b>Family Name: </b>{{key}} -- Address: {{value[0].address}}
    <div ng-repeat="familyMember in value">
      <div ng-show="familyMember.familySize > 1">
        {{familyMember.name}} prefers <span ng-repeat="hobby in familyMember.hobbies">{{hobby.activity}} on {{hobby.preferredOn}} <span ng-show="$index!== familyMember.hobbies.length - 1">and </span></span>
        <div>CHILDREN</div>
        </div>
      <div ng-show="familyMember.familySize === 0">
        {{familyMember.name}} prefers <span ng-repeat="hobby in familyMember.hobbies">{{hobby.activity}} on {{hobby.preferredOn}} <span ng-show="$index!== familyMember.hobbies.length - 1">and </span></span>
        </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it was provided before I could complete my Major Edit, and I felt sorry for making you waste time upon an incorrect question.

Comment: @Gargaroz I updated my answer according to your changes. Actually the main logic did not change; I only made some modifications to view.